# How do I import Flask from Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I am running:

```py
from flask import Flask

app=Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000,debug=True)
    
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "Welkom op mijn eerste Flask-website"
```

Flask is successfully installed.

Error message displays:

```
    from Flask import Flask
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Flask'
```

Comment: The error is always correct, so think about what that might mean. There is no module named `Flask`, with an uppercase `F`, because you installed `flask`, with a lowercase `f`. So the import statement is `from flask`, not `from Flask`. Module names are case sensitive.

Comment: Hi @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, this also doesn't solve it...
But thanks for the tip, I will keep that in mind next time.

Comment: Then update your post: you now know what the correct syntax is, update your code, try to run it, and put the results for _that_ in your post because as currently written. And talk about how you installed it, because if you're not running a virtual environment that you ran `python -m pip install Flask` in, for example, using a virtual environment so you can properly install project dependencies will be part of getting things to run.

Comment: He mike, the output is exactly the same.
It is the same error

Comment: I did make sure that I had Flask installed, it is the newest version currently active

Comment: The output _cannot_ be the same, because the code in the error that you're still showing in your post, `from Flask import Flask`, no longer exists in your code if you updated it, and so _cannot_ be reported by Python.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to check.  Just run a python shell from terminal and type:

```
>>> from flask import Flask
```

You'll either get an error like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
>>>
```

or you'll just get a prompt back.

```
>>>
```

In either case, run

```
>>> quit()
```

to exit the python shell.

The first case means that whatever environment you're in now doesn't yet have Flask installed. The second case means you do.

If you don't, from the terminal prompt run

```
pip install Flask
```

and repeat the experiment with the Python shell.

So this may all seem obvious and trivial, but most likely, whatever you're running into has to do with the environment within whatever tool you're using.  Perhaps VSCode or PyCharm leaves you in a different world?  Maybe it's a virtual environment (venv)?